# Python : Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list :

```
lis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e']
```

I am trying to use comprehensions to get values which are duplicate.

```
duplicates = set([x for x in lis if lis.count(x) > 1])
```

This returns :

{'d','e'}

Now I create a list out of above set :

```
duplicates = list(set([x for x in lis if lis.count(x) > 1]))
```

I get output as :

['e', 'd']

Why the order changes?

Comment: `set` data structure is not ordered

Comment: BTW, this is a highly inefficient algorithm. Don't use a `set`, use a collections `Counter`, something like `[k for k,v in Counter(data) if v > 1]`

Answer (score 0):

`set` does not guarantee the order, `dict` does.

```
>> duplicates = dict.fromkeys([x for x in lis if lis.count(x) > 1], None)

>> duplicates = list(duplicates); duplicates
['d', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Set stores the elements in a random manner.
Try running this code multiple times and see the outputs.

```
s = {"a","b","g","f"}
print(s)
```